# can’t add an alias to my apache2 server

Tags: server, apache2, alias

I want to access my folder `/home/ut/programmes/Programmation/p5-linux/Projets/` from `localhost/p5.js`

With this configuration of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` (in the `<VirtualHost *:80>` markup) :

```
Alias "/p5.js" "/home/ut/programmes/Programmation/p5-linux/Projets"
<Directory "/home/ut/programmes/Programmation/p5-linux/Projets">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

http://localhost/p5.js returns 404 not found.

———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

EDIT :

removing the slash as such :

```
Alias /p5.js "/home/ut/programmes/Programmation/p5-linux/Projets"
<Directory "/home/ut/programmes/Programmation/p5-linux/Projets">
```

solves the 404 error, but now I get a 403 error, and I find really no way to fix that error. I tried to change permissions of my folder, change owner, nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
Alias /p5.js/ "/home/ut/programmes/Programmation/p5-linux/Projets/"
```

to

```
Alias "/p5.js/" "/home/ut/programmes/Programmation/p5-linux/Projets/"
```

Or:

```
Alias /p5.js/ "/home/ut/programmes/Programmation/p5-linux/Projets/"
```

to

```
Alias "/p5.js" "/home/ut/programmes/Programmation/p5-linux/Projets"
```

Source:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

Comment: I still get the 404 error with this edit

Comment: Please check the cases of the path, make sure its correct.

Comment: Please restart your apache also, and check permissions for the file

Comment: the slashes at the end were actually the problem. 
′/p5.js′ works whether I add the quotation mark or not.